# var SM = (function{ ... }()) で宣言された変数に、メソッドが生成される仕組み・条件が知りたい

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

```
var SM = (function () {

  var my = {};

  my.get = function (key) {
      return localStorage.getItem(key);
  }
  my.put = function (key, value) {
      return localStorage.setItem(key, value);
  }
  my.delete = function (key) {
      return localStorage.removeItem(key);
  }
  return my;
}());
```

このコードを実行した後に

```
console.dir(SM);
```

とするとSMのメソッドとして `get()`  `put()` `delete()` の3つが定義されていることが
わかりますが、これは何故でしょうか。

Javaとかの感覚では

```
SM.my.get(key)
```

ならわかるのですが、そのままSMという変数にこのメソッドが生えていることが
難しく感じました。

なぜこのような挙動をするのか、ご存知の方、教えていただけないでしょうか。

ちなみにこのコードは[こちら](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/jp/opensource/library/os-extendchrome/)でGoogleChromeExtensionのチュートリアルとして紹介されていました。

よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

本当にすいません、これ自己解決しました・・・。
単純に関数内で `return my` しているからなんですね。

その箇所を見逃していました。
お騒がせして申し訳ありません。

Comment: `return my` した上で即時関数を呼び出しているからです。(最後の `()`)

Answer (score 4):

もう答えを突き止めたようですが、一言加えますと、この書き方は[IIFE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) (Immediately Invoked Function Expression)、もしくは即時関数といい、JavaScriptでよく用いられます。

Java、C言語、C++などと違い、JavaScriptの変数のスコープはブロック（`{}`）ではなく、回りの関数で区切っています。

だから、回りに影響を与えずに変数を使いたい場合はIIFEが使えます。IIFE内の変数は外側に漏れません。

```js
var total = 30;

if (true) {
    // 以上と同じtotalです { } 括弧は関係ありません
    var total = 40;
}

var otherTotal = (function() {
  // subTotalはこの中でしか存在しません
  var subTotal = 5;

  // 外側のtotalとは別の変数です
  var total = subTotal + 8 * 9;

  return total;
})();

console.log(total);           // 40
console.log(otherTotal);      // 77
console.log(typeof subTotal); // "undefined"
```